# How to set element's id in Python's xml.dom.minidom?

Tags: python, xml, dom, minidom

How to? Created a document and an element:

```
import xml.dom.minidom as d
a=d.Document()
b=a.createElement('test')
```

setIdAttribute doesn't work :(

```
b.setIdAttribute('something')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 835, in setIdAttribute
    self.setIdAttributeNode(idAttr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 843, in setIdAttributeNode
    raise xml.dom.NotFoundErr()
xml.dom.NotFoundErr
```

And if I set this by hand, getElementById can't find it.

```
b.setAttribute('id', 'something')
a.getElementById('something')
```

What I have to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two things are wrong here.

1. `Document.getElementById` will only find elements that are actually in the document. Here you've created `b` but not actually added it to the document. (It's exactly the same in JavaScript.)
2. You have to mark `id` as an ID attribute using `setIdAttribute`. (There's no need to do this in JavaScript because in HTML documents, attributes named `id` are automatically considered to be ID attributes, logically enough. But XML does *not* automatically treat attributes named `id` as IDs; you can either explicitly declare that they are in your DTD or call `setIdAttribute` individually for every ID attribute. And I am not sure the DTD thing will work with minidom, which is not a full DOM implementation.)

Like so:

```
import xml.dom.minidom as d
a = d.Document()
b = a.createElement('test')
a.appendChild(b)
b.setAttribute('id', 'x')
b.setIdAttribute('id')
```

After that, `getElementById` works:

```
>>> a.getElementById('x')
<DOM Element: test at 0xb77712ec>
```

Comment: It doesn't work like same thing in JavaScript? So how do I search for elements in whole document - including child nodes?

Comment: Edited the answer to clarify how this is different from JavaScript.

Comment: document.createElement == minidom.Element and document.appendChild.
after the append, nothing happened, same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the name of the id attribute to the DTD should help. For example, if you want every to set the `id` as the id attribute for all `<div>` elements, you can set up your DTD as follows:

`<!DOCTYPE div [<!ATTLIST div id ID #IMPLIED>]>`

This is a working example:

```
>>> from xml.dom.minidom import parse, parseString                              
>>> data='<!DOCTYPE div [<!ATTLIST div id ID #IMPLIED>]><div><div id="foo">FOO word</div><div id="bar">BAR word</div></div>'
>>> x=parseString(data)
>>> x.getElementById('foo')
<DOM Element: div at 0x1126440>
>>> x.getElementById('foo').toxml()
u'<div id="foo">FOO word</div>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, the easiest way to do this for each element in the document is to parse the full DOM once like this :

```
import xml.dom.minidom as dom
xml = dom.parse("my_file.xml")

# Parse every element and set the ID attribute
for nodes in xml.getElementsByTagName("*"):
    nodes.setIdAttribute("id")

# Now this works (and it is efficient)
test = xml.getElementById("some_id")
```