# Do namespaced id's exist or what is android:id from the XML point of view?

Tags: android, python, xml, xslt, dom

I built a Python script (with minidom) to manipulate the layout of an Android app, which is defined in an XML file. Widgets are elements in the `android` namespace, for example:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/myId" android:text="..." />
```

Note the `android:id` attribute and its required format `@+id/...`. I didn't find a way to pick that element with `getElementById()`. Maybe it's because I don't know minidom, but more likely it's because I don't understand XML namespaces deeply.

I remember that `id` is an attribute to uniquely identify an element in a tree. I never saw a namespaced ID, so my guess is that `android:id` *isn't really an ID*, but just an attribute which happens to be called `id` in the `android` namespace. In this case there's no way to `getElementById`, because it works with XML id's. Currently I traverse the dom and check the android:id attribute to get my target element, but this technique is obviously less flexible than `getElementById` directly

*Disclaimer: I tagged this with xslt because I think that xslt people can know the answer since they are used to working with XML and namespaces*

Comment: As always some sample input and desired output XML would really, really help. I suspect that you are correct that android is a namespace but you should be able to check this by seeing if the there is an xmlns declaration at the start of the XML document.

Comment: `android` **is** the namespace, there's no doubt. The question is if  an attribute named `id` scoped in a namespace can be used to `getElementById`. If you want to see a source XML [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) are some

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - I found something else that may be of help to you. Apparently it depends on what has been listed of being of type "ID". Where is that defin ed and can you influence it? I don't know :-( But check [How to set element's id in Python's xml.dom.minidom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971186/how-to-set-elements-id-in-pythons-xml-dom-minidom)

See extract below from http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html

getElementById introduced in DOM Level 2 
Returns the Element whose ID is given by elementId. If no such element exists, returns null. Behavior is not defined if more than one element has this ID.
 Note: The DOM implementation must have information that says which attributes are of type ID. Attributes with the name "ID" are not of type ID unless so defined. Implementations that do not know whether attributes are of type ID or not are expected to return null.

Comment: So, xml defines an `id` datatype, and it's up to the DOM implementation recognize it and make it available through `getElementById`. My implementation is *minidom*, and I have not found a way to get it working

Comment: If I read the linked answer correctly, you can set an attribute name as ID easily by using SetIdAttribute. Looking a little bit further, searching for minidom doc, I found that there also is a SetIdAttributeNS available in minidom, which seems to set an attribute name + namespace as ID. I hope that will be useful to you.

Comment: it's a chicken and egg problem: `setIdAttribute` is defined for [`Element`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.2/Lib/xml/dom/minidom.py), not for Document, so you must locate the element **first**, then can retrieve with `getElementById`. But I guess this is no very useful :)

Comment: @Raffaele You could be right, but because being an ID attribute is element-independent, it should be available on document-level indeed, and if it isn't, then logic dictates that invoking it on any element (for instance, the root element), should have the desired effect. Just guessing here, of course; I have no experience whatsoever with minidom.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, attributes can have namespaces. The best known example of attribute namespace is the namespace declaration itself:

```
xmlns:someNamespace="someUri"
```

The only advantage in using namespaces that I see, is that the same attribute name may be used more than once, when assigned separate namespaces, such as in

```
<x xmlns:n1="http://www.w3.org" 
   xmlns:n2="http://www.my.org" >
  <good n1:a="1"  n2:a="2" />
</x>
```

Not sure what one would need that for though...

Now for selecting namespaced attributes.
In XSLT/Xpath this is done in normal fashion, including the namespace of course; don't forget the @ character. Example for the above XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:n1="http://www.w3.org"
    xmlns:n2="http://www.my.org">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="//good">
        <root>
            <n1><xsl:value-of select="./@n1:a"/></n1>
            <n2><xsl:value-of select="./@n2:a"/></n2>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

gives

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:n1="http://www.w3.org" xmlns:n2="http://www.my.org">
    <n1>1</n1>
    <n2>2</n2>
</root>
```

Comment: You are mistaken that avoiding collisions is the only purpose of namespaces.  Attribute namespaces allow you to insert attributes from one namespace into documents of any arbitrary namespace; so with namespaces I can put an `xlink:href` into any document, and I can mark any node as `xml:lang="en"`, but without namespaces I couldn't do that -- I could put `href="..."` or `lang="en"` but the meanings could be completely different.  The namespace for xlink carries the additional semantic information about what `xlink:href` means.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really need a XSLT example, my question is more theoretical (see the disclaimer). One API to access XML is the DOM, which defines `getElementById`. This works with the special xml `id` attribute. I wonder if the same DOM function can be used to access a *namespaced* id, making it somewhat a special attribute, or if it's a normal attribute and need you to traverse the DOM (which you accomplish in xslt through `select="./@prefix:attr"`)

Comment: @DietrichEpp I agree. It's just that apart from xsl stylesheet headers I don't see that much namespaces being used - I would like to see some clarifying non-laboratory examples, would you know where I can find these?

Comment: (continues) Using `getElementById` one needs nothing but the ID, while all other ways requires some knowlege of the structure (thus is less flexible)

Comment: @Maestro13: server side Java libraries use namespaces a lot :) Google for *JSP taglibs*

Comment: @Maestro13 , yes, but again you need to have some knowledge of the context. I use my script to simply remove element with known `android:id`. It they used *regular* xml id, I could simply get them with `getElementById`. But with the namespaced version I need to locate the element in some other way

Comment: @Maestro13: You see namespaces being used in a lot of DocBook workflows (well, Docbook 5, not Docbook 4), even when they don't use XSLT you need to use other non-Docbook namespaces in order to understand the document.  Workflows that rely on more modern validation schemes use namespaces to specify schema; as Raffaele mentioned, this is common in Java (esp. JEE).  The whole practice of namespaces tend to show up when you need to use truly generic tools to process XML, and you won't care for namespaces if you are always working with custom XML processors. It also lets you put inline SVG in HTML.