# Minidom getElementById not working

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, minidom

Minidom's getElementById function is returning None for any entry I pass to it.

For example, this code:

```
l = minidom.parseString('<node id="node">Node</node>')
print(l.getElementById("node"))
```

Prints "None" on my computer.

I must be doing something here wrong but I can't figure it out!

I'm running Python 3.3.2 if that helps.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I'm still curious why this method exists if it doesn't seem to work at all. I had a quick look but I didn't really find any explanation.

Comment: Answere is here :
https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-getElBId
you have attributes named "id" but they are not of type "ID"
Find a way to type them with DTD or something and it will work

Comment: To declare the `id` attribute, one can use `myElement.setIdAttribute('id')`. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971186/how-to-set-elements-id-in-pythons-xml-dom-minidom

Comment: You might want to make your question clearer by giving different names to tag and attribute value. Just `node` for both is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get elements with name="node"

```
l.getElementsByTagName("node")
```

If you want to get elements with attribute having an attribute "id" with value "node", use [xpath](https://code.google.com/p/py-dom-xpath/):

```
import xpath
xpath.find("//*['id=node']",l) #search for all elements with an attribute id="node"
```

Comment: This returns a list of elements with the tag name, not the ID - in the actual document I am using this would not be useful

Comment: so do you want all the elements having the attribute 'id' with value 'node' ? in that case, you will have to use xpath.

Comment: I see... I will look it up. Thanks. (put that into your answer and I'll go ahead and accept it)

Answer (score 3):

I used another approach to get Elemnts by ID (meaning the XML-attribute "id"), since I wanted to only use [xml.dom.minidom.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html)

Here is an example from my work:

```
#import minidom
from xml.dom.minidom import parse as p
#parse your XML-document
cmmn_doc = p("document.xml")
#Get all child nodes of your root-element or any element surrounding your "target" (in my example "cmmn:casePlanModel")
notelist = cmmn_doc.getElementsByTagName("cmmn:casePlanModel")[0].childNodes

#Now find the element via the id-tag
def find_element(id):
    i=0
    for i in range(len(notelist)):
        if notelist[i].getAttribute("id") == id:
        return notelist[i].nodeName #(or whatever you want to do)

#Call find_element with the id you are looking for
find_element(id)
```

XML from the example:

```
    <cmmn:casePlanModel id="CasePlanModel_1" name="A CasePlanModel">
      <cmmn:planItem id="PlanItem_1" definitionRef="Task_1" />
      <cmmn:planItem id="PlanItem_08uai3q" definitionRef="HumanTask_0pgsk2i" />
      <cmmn:planItem id="PlanItem_0crahv8" definitionRef="HumanTask_0jvecsr">
        <cmmn:itemControl id="PlanItemControl_0tdwp8g">
          <cmmn:repetitionRule id="RepetitionRule_03ky93m" />
          <cmmn:requiredRule id="RequiredRule_1klzaio" />
          <cmmn:manualActivationRule id="ManualActivationRule_1rek2bf" />
        </cmmn:itemControl>
      </cmmn:planItem>
      <cmmn:planItem id="PlanItem_08kswcr" definitionRef="HumanTask_14zxi11" />
      <cmmn:planItem id="PlanItem_12b1nkx" definitionRef="ProcessTask_10xuu3g">
        <cmmn:exitCriterion id="EntryCriterion_09gio4l" sentryRef="Sentry_0hst9b5" />
      </cmmn:planItem>
      <cmmn:planItem id="PlanItem_1v34h5m" definitionRef="CaseTask_0hwjce3">
        <cmmn:entryCriterion id="EntryCriterion_1j8r6j1" sentryRef="Sentry_1ii8w5d" />
      </cmmn:planItem>
      <cmmn:planItem id="PlanItem_0wroqsx" definitionRef="EventListener_17yxe7z" />
      <cmmn:sentry id="Sentry_0hst9b5" />
      <cmmn:sentry id="Sentry_1ii8w5d">
        <cmmn:planItemOnPart id="PlanItemOnPart_1gt5jrc" sourceRef="PlanItem_12b1nkx">        <cmmn:standardEvent>complete</cmmn:standardEvent>
</cmmn:planItemOnPart>
        <cmmn:planItemOnPart id="PlanItemOnPart_01b6uw3" sourceRef="PlanItem_0wroqsx">        <cmmn:standardEvent>occur</cmmn:standardEvent>
</cmmn:planItemOnPart>
      </cmmn:sentry>
      <cmmn:task id="Task_1" name="Simple Task" />
      <cmmn:humanTask id="HumanTask_0pgsk2i" name="Human Task" />
      <cmmn:humanTask id="HumanTask_0jvecsr" name="Human_Blocking" isBlocking="false" />
      <cmmn:humanTask id="HumanTask_14zxi11" name="Human_mit_Anhang">
        <cmmn:planningTable id="PlanningTable_1yxv7gm">
          <cmmn:discretionaryItem id="DiscretionaryItem_0ne79yh" definitionRef="DecisionTask_1ecc5v8" />
        </cmmn:planningTable>
      </cmmn:humanTask>
      <cmmn:decisionTask id="DecisionTask_1ecc5v8" name="Descritionary to Human Task" />
      <cmmn:processTask id="ProcessTask_10xuu3g" name="Prozess Task" />
      <cmmn:caseTask id="CaseTask_0hwjce3" name="Case Task" />
      <cmmn:eventListener id="EventListener_17yxe7z" name="EventListener" />
    </cmmn:casePlanModel>
```

I found this way more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

From the instruction you typed, I understand you are trying to get the element which `id` value is `node`.

The solution is to loop over all your XML elements (well, you have only one in this situation, but it does not matter), and then check if that element has an attribute called `id` and the value of that attribute is `node`.

Let us translate this logic into a program:

```
>>> from xml.dom import minidom
>>> xml_string = '<node id="node">Node</node>'
>>> xml_doc = minidom.parseString(xml_string)
>>> elements = xml_doc.getElementsByTagName('node')
>>> for element in elements:
...     if element.hasAttribute('id') and element.getAttribute('id') == 'node':
...             print(element.toxml())
... 
<node id="node">Node</node>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def getElementById(doc, _id):
    for c in doc.childNodes:
        if c.nodeType not in [c.DOCUMENT_NODE, c.TEXT_NODE, c.DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE, c.COMMENT_NODE]:
        #[ATTRIBUTE_NODE, CDATA_SECTION_NODE, ENTITY_NODE, PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION_NODE, NOTATION_NODE
            if c.getAttribute('id') == _id:
                return c
        res_for_c = getElementById(c, _id)
        if res_for_c:
            return res_for_c
    return None
```

Answer (score 0):

Looping through every nodes of the document each time you look for an element by ID may be very long and a waste of resource.

You can do it only once with this code :

```
import xml.dom.minidom as dom
xml = dom.parse("my_file.xml")

# Parse every element and set the ID attribute
for nodes in xml.getElementsByTagName("*"):
    nodes.setIdAttribute("id")

# Now this works (and it is efficient)
test = xml.getElementById("some_id")
```