# XHTML Parsing using minidom

Tags: python, parsing, xhtml, minidom

I want to parse this to get the weather report. Using python minidom

```
                <div class="pull-left" id="current-temps-cont">
                    <h4 class="myforecast-current">Cloudy</h4>
                    <h1 class="myforecast-current-lrg">57&#176;F</h1>
                    <h3 class="myforecast-current-sm">14&#176;C</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
```

now i cant just getElementsByTagName("h4") because i will be doing this parse on alot of different weather websites so the amount of h4's tag might be different on each website. But, all of the info i need no matter what state i choose will all be under id="current-temp-cont"

I currently am working with something like this but i keep

```
import sys
import xml.dom.minidom

document = xml.dom.minidom.parse(sys.argv[1])

weather = document.getElementById("current-temps-cont")
weatherReal = weather.getElementsByTagName("h4")
print(weatherReal)
```

~
When i run i get. Can someone explain what im missing or if im approaching this the wrong way?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "x.py", line 7, in <module>
weatherReal = weather.getElementsByTagName("h4")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getElementsByTagName'
```

Comment: lxml + xpath would be more precise, is that an option?

Comment: it is not. i can only use minidom.

Comment: Add a representative sample of `sys.argv[1]` to your question please so it becomes a  [Minimum Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i am using wget to get the weather. so wget https://forecast-v3.weather.gov/point/34.0535,-118.2453 Than i am converting to a html file, than using tagsoup to convert it to an xhtml file in which im doing the parsing. Im sending the xhtml file as my arg

Comment: html structure looks fairly simple so something in those conversions could be messing it. There's no apparent reason to fail getting the element by id.

Comment: Why exactly can you only use minidom?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, that is a [bug](https://github.com/html5lib/html5lib-python/issues/74) that has never been solved (yes, long time ago already). You can browse the source code of `getElementById()` function [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/xml/dom/minidom.py) if you have time.

You can circumvent the issue by having to fetch the elements by their tag name, and then filter them using a combination of `hasAttribute()` and `getAttribute()` functions as I did in my solution here: [Minidom getElementById not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24653950/minidom-getelementbyid-not-working/49968898#49968898)

Comment: I doubt that it's a bug as such. In DOM, `getElementById()` doesn't mean "get the element whose attribute named 'id' has the value ...", it means "get the element whose attribute of type ID has the value ...". Minidom clearly needs to be told that the attribute named 'id' is of type ID. HTML parsers kind of know this, but it's not inherently true in XML, which is why the DOCTYPE needs to tell minidom this.

Comment: Interesting point of view. I am curious to know what you mean by *Minidom clearly needs to be told that the attribute named 'id' is of type ID.*. I mean, if you could just provide your own answer (even just with a simple XML string), many users would be glad (me included) because this issue is mentioned several times on this website and elsewhere. Thank you @Alohci